# How to remove NAs and values corresponding to them in R?

Tags: r, na

I have data consisting of values before and after an experiment. For example:

```
before after
2.5   2.2
3     4
1.8   2.4
NA    3
4     NA

before <- c(2.5 ,3 ,1.8 ,NA ,4)
after <- c(2.2, 4, 2.4, 3 ,NA)
```

What I want to do is remove `NA`s and the values corresponding to it. In our example, I want to remove `NA`s which will convert my data to

```
before after
2.5   2.2
3     4
1.8   2.4
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

```
before <- c(2.5 ,3 ,1.8 ,NA ,4)
after <- c(2.2, 4, 2.4, 3 ,NA)

df = data.frame(before,after)

df = df[complete.cases(df),]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Or use

```
 subset(df1, !(is.na(before)|is.na(after)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you may use na.omit (as commented by Roland)

```
df = data.frame(before,after)
df = na.omit(df)
```